# setTimeout on a memoized function

Tags: javascript

Assuming ES5, I want to do something like this.

```
var memoizedFunc = (function(params) {
  var cache = {};
  var mem = function(params) {
    //Do some stuff involving the cache
    return someResult;
  }
  return mem;
}());
setTimeOut(memoizedFunc(params), 2000);
```

The timeout isn't working on the mem function however, how could I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the *function reference* instead of the result of its execution

```
setTimeOut(function(){memoizedFunc(params)}, 2000);
```